# Multidimensional vector to unique_ptr array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, unique-ptr

I want to remake part of my code to work with unique_ptr instead of 2D-vector
Here is how I used to populate the result vector:

```
    outputFileHandler.open(outputFileName);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < result[i].size(); ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < threadCount; ++j)
            if (!result[j].empty())
                outputFileHandler << result[j][i] << " ";

    if (result[0].size() > 1)
        for (size_t i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i)
            if (result[i].size() == result[0].size())
                outputFileHandler << result[i][result[i].size() - 1] << " ";

    outputFileHandler.close();
```

Which now seems to me quite a mess. 
How can I remake this part to be used with unique_ptr array?
Thank you

Comment: Why not using `std::vector` at all?

Comment: 1) this doesn't populate anything, it prints stuff to file. 2) Why use `std::unique_ptr ` when you already get RAII from the vector?